# Add a string to a file ONLY if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, file

I'm teaching myself Java and came across a problem which I have no idea how to solve.
I want to basically check two things:
1. If a file doesn't exist - create it! if it does, do nothing.
2. If the file contains a given String, do nothing, if it does not contain it - add it! (don't overwrite it)
2nd one is more important but I couldn't figure out the first one either.

Tried looking online on how to make sure a file exists, or how to only add String to a file if it doesn't exist, but it just doesn't work for some reason.

```java
main{        
String s;
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("s.txt", true);
            File file = new File("s.txt");
            doesStringExist(s,fw);   
} 

public void doesStringExist(String s, FileWriter fw) throws IOException {
        String scan;
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(fw)));
        while ((scan = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (scan.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if(scan.contains(s) {
                System.out.println(s + " already exists in S.txt");
            }else{
                fw.write(s);
            }
        }
    }








// I made a different method for checking if it exists or not because i just like it like that being more organized
```

Currently I expect the code to only check if a string exists, if it does, do nothing (send exists message), if it doesn't exist, add it to the file.
also I want to make it so it checks if the file exists.

Comment: What actually happens when you do run your current code?

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) appears in your code, and it has an `exists()` method. Have you considered what it might do? But you can also depend on exceptions, there is a `FileNotFoundException`, you may be encountering when a file does not exist.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Current code just creates the file, put doesn't insert anything in it.

Comment: @tevemadar I have, but I couldn't understand how it works, I have to first create the file then check if it exists, because if I don't, it just won't let me launch the program.

Comment: `new File(...)` creates a file-handling object for Java itself. It may or may not refer to an actual file on a disk. This is why it can actually check that if the given file is there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly said I might not use `exists()` after all, just go with the exception-path:

```
File file = new File("s.txt");  // this is a file handle, s.txt may or may not exist
boolean found=false;  // flag for target txt being present
try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
  String line;
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null)  // classic way of reading a file line-by-line
    if(line.equals("something")){
      found=true;
      break;  // if the text is present, we do not have to read the rest after all
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){}

if(!found){  // if the text is not found, it has to be written
  try(PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true))){  // it works with
                                                                   // non-existing files too
    bw.println("something");
  }
}
```

Comment: @sElfes: Well, this one expects an entire line to match (`line.equals()`). If the text is just a part of a line, `line.contains()` could be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st one you can use the below :

```
File f = new File("F:\\program.txt"); 
if (f.exists()) 
    System.out.println("Exists");
```

Comment: I want it to first check if it exists, then create it, because I don't want it to replace the current file, so if it doesn't exist, it'll just create it, but if it exists, I'm guessing it's going to replace the current file, and then just check if the file exists.

Comment: @sElfes see the explanation in the comment under the question. A `File` object is not a file on the disk.

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks, first solution's solved, now I only need to figure out how to check if a string exists in a file if it does, do nothing, if it doesn't add it

Comment: You need to read the File line by line and compare it with the String you have. If you find the String ignore else if you reach the end of the File you can add this line. https://www.journaldev.com/709/java-read-file-line-by-line

Comment: @Geek How do I know when is the end of a file? searched it up online but none of them answer directly